# img not loading in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS file:

```css
.one_quarter {
  width: 225px;
}

.updates,
.updates a {
  color: #C0BAB6;
  background-color: #333333;
}

#header,
#wrapper,
#footer {
  display: block;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: #afaeae;
  background-color: #232323;
}

address,
article,
aside,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.clear:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
}

.clear {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  line-height: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.imgholder,
.imgl,
.imgr {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
  text-align: center;
}

.imgl {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
  clear: left;
}

.imgr {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 15px 15px;
  clear: right;
}

#wrapper #content #services {}

#wrapper #content #services ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#wrapper #content #services ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#wrapper #content #services ul li.last {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#wrapper #content #services ul li article {}

#container #content #services ul li article figure {}

#wrapper #content #services ul li article figure img {
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
}

#wrapper #content .more {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> Title of page </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet1" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/css/fontawesome.min.css">
</head>
<div class="wrapper updates">
  <div id="content">
    <section id="services" class="last clear">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <article class="clear">
            <figure><img src="images/demo/180x150.gif" alt="">
              <figcaption>
                <h2>Indonectetus facilis leo nibh</h2>
                <p>content content content <a href="#" title="Free Website Templates">link to other content</a>. For full terms of use of this template please read our <a href="https://www.os-templates.com/template-terms">website template licence</a>.</p>
                <footer class="more"><a href="#">Read More &raquo;</a></footer>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </article>
        </li>
        <li class="last">
          <article class="clear">
            <figure><img src="images/demo/180x150.gif" alt="">
              <figcaption>
                <h2>Indonectetus facilis leo nibh</h2>
                <p>You can use and modify the template for both personal and commercial use. You must keep all copyright information and credit links in the template and associated files. For more HTML5 templates visit <a href="https://www.os-templates.com/">free website templates</a>.</p>
                <footer class="more"><a href="#">Read More &raquo;</a></footer>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </article>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

It should look like this from the template:
[image]

But the image is not loading where it should and 'Read more' is not being aligned right. Thanks for your help in advance

[[image]

Could you please advise what I have omitted? For the link I had tried to add paddign and margin but the link is not moving.

Comment: please post a [repro] and pay extra attention for the word **minimal**!! I doubt that it is necessary to post  hudnrets of CSS liens to show that an image is not loading. Also focus on one question not 2. What error messages do you get? 403 or 404 error while tying to laod the image?

Comment: @tacoshy Yes, i will be more careful next time. Cheers!

Comment: Your styles are referred to `#wrapper` which is an id but you never define it in your styles but a class. You should add `id="wrapper"` @Slartibartfast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned the latest CSS rules to elements inside an element with the id `wrapper`, but in your HTML you use this as class name instead.

Replace

```html
<div class="wrapper updates">
```

with

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="updates">
```

to get it working.

```css
.one_quarter {
  width: 225px;
}

.updates,
.updates a {
  color: #C0BAB6;
  background-color: #333333;
}

#header,
#wrapper,
#footer {
  display: block;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: #afaeae;
  background-color: #232323;
}

address,
article,
aside,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.clear:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
}

.clear {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  line-height: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.imgholder,
.imgl,
.imgr {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
  text-align: center;
}

.imgl {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
  clear: left;
}

.imgr {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 15px 15px;
  clear: right;
}

#wrapper #content #services {}

#wrapper #content #services ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#wrapper #content #services ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#wrapper #content #services ul li.last {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#wrapper #content #services ul li article {}

#container #content #services ul li article figure {}

#wrapper #content #services ul li article figure img {
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
}

#wrapper #content .more {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> Title of page </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet1" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/css/fontawesome.min.css">
</head>
<div id="wrapper" class="updates">
  <div id="content">
    <section id="services" class="last clear">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <article class="clear">
            <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/250/180" alt="">
              <figcaption>
                <h2>Indonectetus facilis leo nibh</h2>
                <p>content content content <a href="#" title="Free Website Templates">link to other content</a>. For full terms of use of this template please read our <a href="https://www.os-templates.com/template-terms">website template licence</a>.</p>
                <footer class="more"><a href="#">Read More &raquo;</a></footer>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </article>
        </li>
        <li class="last">
          <article class="clear">
            <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/250/180" alt="">
              <figcaption>
                <h2>Indonectetus facilis leo nibh</h2>
                <p>You can use and modify the template for both personal and commercial use. You must keep all copyright information and credit links in the template and associated files. For more HTML5 templates visit <a href="https://www.os-templates.com/">free website templates</a>.</p>
                <footer class="more"><a href="#">Read More &raquo;</a></footer>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </article>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

Regarding the images: Check the paths and the console and network panels in the developer console.

Comment: this equals a typo caused issue and should have been commented and flagged as such instead of giving an answer. Typo caused issues have no value for SO (usign an ID as class or vice-versa falls udner the same list)